# Mocking Methods within Classes

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I've read a lot of information online about mocking entire classes. However, I have a class with multiple methods; for example:

```
class A():
    def methoda(param1, param2):
        do things
        return thing
    def methodb(param3):
        do things (including something calling methoda)
```

How can I mock out methoda in a testing file to return a desired value so that I can test methodb? I don't want to mock out the entire class.

What I've tried doing:

```
from mock import patch, mock, MagicMock
from sourceA.models import ClassName
from django.test import TestCase

class ClassTest(TestCase):

    @patch('sourceA.models.ClassName.methodA')
    def test_method(self, mock_method_return):
        mock_method_return.return_value = 10
        instance = ClassName()
        instance.methodB #METHOD B CALLS METHOD A; I want method A to return 10
        print "OUTPUT", instance.FIELDA #Debug Tool - Field A is modified by Method B, based on the return value of method A
    assert instance.FIELDA == 10
```

I have also tried this:

```
class ClassTest(TestCase):

    @patch('sourceA.models.ClassName.methodA', return_value=10)
    def test_method(self, mock_method_return):
        instance = Mock(spec=ClassName())
        instance.methodB #METHOD B CALLS METHOD A; I want method A to return 10
------ OR instance methodB = MagicMock(return_value=10) and then instance.MethodB
        print "OUTPUT", instance.FIELDA #Debug Tool - Field A is modified by Method B, based on the return value of method A
    self.assertEqual(instance.FIELDA, 10)
```

I'm not sure what else I should try/what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You would first test methoda with a value you know is correct and then mentally note the output. When you call methoda with this value within methodb, note that the methoda call will be replaced with the known output.

Comment: I know I can do the same thing easily without a mock, but I want to know how to use the mock package to do this.

Comment: Ah, here is what I used back in school: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-mocking-in-python

Comment: Did you try just `patch('A.methoda')`?

Comment: Doesn't patching only work for entire classes/objects?

Comment: Added more to the code to clarify the question.